# PostgreSQL - serial increment is not ordinal and shared between other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `words` and `definitions`. 
At `words` table `wordid` is primary key and serial.
At `definitions` table `definitionid` is primary key and serial.

Increment is not ordinal and increment continues from other table.

words table

```
wordid
------
1
2
(3 is not here)
(4 is not here)
5
```

definitions table:

```
definitionid
------------
3
4
(5 is not here)
6
7
```

What I want is: each table's serial value must be separate from each other.
wordid must be 1, 2, 3 ... and definitionid must be 1, 2, 3 ...

How I can do that?

Comment: First, why you want it? After couple of DELETE's you'll get gaps back anyway.  And gaps make DB no harm.

Comment: "*What I want is: each table's serial value must be separate from each other*" - which happens automatically when you define those columns as `serial` - each one uses a different sequence to generate the numbers. So if what you wrote in your first paragraph is true, then you don't need to do anything

Comment: check the default value of each serial. maybe you use the same .seq for both.

Comment: @FatFreddy  How do I check this? I am new to PostgreSQL

Comment: something like that:
SELECT
table_schema,
table_name,
column_name,
column_default 
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
table_name='your_table' AND table_schema='your_schema';

Comment: In `psql`: `\d words` and `\d definitions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am rather wary of sharing ids between tables.  There may be another way to represent the data the way that you want -- for instance, putting everything into a single table.

That said, Postgres offers a capability called [inheritance](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=192a4f6a6c61b87b8c20fd0ea6ef645b) that allows you to do what you want.

Basically, you can do:

```
create table base (
    base_id serial
);

create table word (
    . . .
) inherits (base);

create table definitions (
    . . . 
) inherits (definitions);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=192a4f6a6c61b87b8c20fd0ea6ef645b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to share ids between tables. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @emert117 . . . You *do* want to share ids between tables if you want them to be interdependent.  There is an alternative using sequences and triggers, but this is much cleaner.

Comment: Are you recommending me to not to change anything?